# Ionic 2 - Lazy Loading Component

Tags: ionic2

In Ionic 2 is it possible to lazy load a component within a page that is not lazy loaded or a component not lazy loaded. That is the page/component I want to insert the lazy load component is declared within the app.component.ts?

If so where is the lazy loaded component declared?

Comment: Within it's own module. Module will be loaded as soon as your application requires it.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create a module file for the share page/component that I want to put the lazy component in? Apart from creating the module file for the shared page/component, do I need to declare that module anyway or is it automatically loaded?

Comment: Create a module for your own component. Import that module in the place you'll need it. Import in in AppModule if you need it as soon as the application boots up. Import it to another pages module, to lazy load the component along with the page.